# Cannot use proxy with Gatsby

Tags: node.js, axios, graphql, environment-variables, gatsby

I'm using `Gatsby` and I'm trying to fetch some API contents using the `Axios` library, so far I have added the following configuration in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
proxy: [
{
    prefix: "/api",
    url: process.env.API_URL,
  },
],
```

where `API_URL` is loaded at the beginning of `gatsby-config.js` using:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

now the problem's that when I perform a request like that:

```
const res = await axios.get("/api/sections")
```

this is executed using `http://localhost:8000/api/sections` which is actually weird 'cause I suppose that `Gatsby` should intercept the `/api` prefix and then use the url that I gave using `API_URL` variable.

I'm running `Gatsby` in dev mode.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`API_URL` is not loaded at the beggining of the `gatsby-config.js`. The following snippet:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Tells Gatsby to look for environment variables in `.env.development` and `.env.production` (both by default running `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` respectively). Since you are not defining an environment file, Gatsby doesn't know what's `process.env.API_URL`.

Create a `.env.development` and `.env.production` in the root of your project and define an `API_URL` variable.

```
API_URL= yourUrl.com
```

Change your axios request to:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const res = await axios.get('/api/sections', {
  proxy: {
    host: process.env.API_URL,
    port: 3000 //remove if not needed
  }
});
```

Afterward, your request will be prefixed.

Gatsby doesn't catch external request if you are using third-party modules. According to [API Proxy docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/api-proxy/) it seems to work only with the native JavaScript `fetch` function.

Comment: I've already defined those files in the root of the project, if I do a `console.log(process.env.API_URL)` before the API request, I can see the correct endpoint, but for some reason Gatsby doesn't use this endpoint the Axios request

Comment: Have you tried to store the `process.env.API_URL` in a variable and use that variable as a parameter? Like `const apiUrl=process.env.API_URL` and then: `url: apiUrl`

Comment: yes, same problem I get in xhr: `http://localhost:8000/api/sections`

Comment: I've added a new snippet with the `axios` request with proxy options.

Comment: Even using the snippet is not working, always had: `http://localhost:8000/api/sections` but API_URL is: `http://localhost:1337`

Comment: What if you try using `fetch`?

Comment: I tried also with fetch and same behavior, I really don't understand..